# Silver Stripe Data

Tags: array

Como colocar a data no formato `d-m-Y` com esses campos?

```
private static $summary_fields = array(
  'Created',
  'LastEdited',
);

private static $field_labels = array(
  'Created' => 'Criado',
  'LastEdited' => 'Logado',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira simpes de fazer em PHP, supondo que a data seja uma string, seria:

```php
function formataData($data)
{  
    $t = strtotime($data);
    return date('d/m/Y ', $t);
}

//entrada: '2020-07-07'
//saida: '07/07/2020'
```